# Why we put "To.String" after i*j?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, for-loop

Why we put `To.String()` after `i*j`?

```
int[] CalculateMultTable = new int[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        Console.Write((i * j).ToString() + "\t");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: What happens when you remove it?

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: Then it may indeed be unnecessary.  I imagine it's there to explicitly define the value as a string because it's being appended with another string.

Comment: This question is unreadable, there are tools to format code when you write a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not technically necessary here, but the person who wrote it may have either:

1. Assumed it was necessary, or
2. Felt it more explicitly defined the operation being performed.

That operation is simply:

```
(i * j) + "\t"
```

Since the intended output is a string, the values being appended to one another should be strings.  In this case the operator is smart enough to figure it out, defaulting non-string values to their `.ToString()` representations.